# Haskell - An error related to types

Tags: function, haskell, types

I have these functions in a Haskell file and they work fine :

```
func1 :: Integer -> (Integer,Integer) -> [[String]] -> ([Char],[Char],[Char],[Char]) -> (Integer,Integer)

func1 distance agent mymap moves = func5 (func3 agent (func2 distance agent mymap) moves)


func2 :: Integer -> (Integer,Integer) -> [[String]] -> [(Integer,Integer)]

func3 :: (Ord a, Ord b) => (b,a) -> [(b,a)] -> ([Char],[Char],[Char],[Char]) -> [(b,a)]

func4 :: (Int,Int) -> (Int,Int) -> ([Char],[Char],[Char],a) -> ([Char],[Char],[Char],[Char]) -> [[[Char]]] -> [[[Char]]]
func5 [(a,b)] = (a,b)
```

But when I write this function :

```
func6 agent distance mymap moves moves2 = func4 agent (func1 distance agent mymap moves) moves moves2 mymap
```

I get this error :

```
*ERROR "play.hs":176 - Type error in application
* * * Expression     : moveWithFood agent (giveNearestCorrect distance agent mymap moves) moves moves2 mymap
* * * Term           : giveNearestCorrect distance agent mymap moves
* * * Type           : (Integer,Integer)
* * * Does not match : (Int,Int)*
```

Same error with ghci:

```
play.hs:176:93:
    Couldn't match expected type `Integer' against inferred type `Int'
      Expected type: (Integer, Integer)
      Inferred type: (Int, Int)
    In the second argument of `giveNearestCorrect', namely `agent'
    In the second argument of `moveWithFood', namely
        `(giveNearestCorrect distance agent mymap moves)'
Failed, modules loaded: none.*
```

I tried several things to solve it but I couldn't succeed. Can you tell me what I should do?
Thanks.

Comment: `Integer` and `Int` are not the same type. You may want to pick one and stick with it.

Comment: @pigworker Which change do you think would be easier to get rid of the problem? Do I have to rewrite the code?

Comment: If you're happy with machine-issue fixed-width numbers, go with `Int`. Perhaps the sensible thing to do would be to use type synonyms like `type Agent = (Int, Int)` and then write `Agent` in types whenever you mean an `Agent`. That'll make it easier to keep your types consistent. Start by rewriting the *types* in your code so they clearly express what you mean. If there's still a problem with the equations, it should then at least be clearer what's amiss.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As pigworker pointed out, `Int` and `Integer` are not the same type. If you have just a few points where you need a "translation", `fromIntegral` might be the way to go.

For common applications `Int` is often good enough (and faster than `Integer`), so I would suggest you try to use this exclusively.

Another possibility would be using the `Num` type-class. Here is an example for a function that works for both `Int` and `Integer`:

```
func1 :: Num a => a -> (a, a) -> [[String]] -> ([Char],[Char],[Char],[Char]) -> (a, a)
```

You might need to use some `fromIntegral` calls inside, depending on your original implementation.

Answer (score 0):

You are using `agent` as the second argument to `func1`/`giveNearestCorrect` (so it must be an `(Integer, Integer)`, according to the type signature), and also as the first argument to `func4`/`moveWithFood` (so it must be an `(Int, Int)`).

`agent` cannot be both an `(Integer, Integer)` *and* an `(Int, Int)`. Choose one, and stick to it: I would follow the advice in pigworker's comment.